# how can i plot graph accoring to time in vb?

Tags: .net, vb.net, graph

I am analising a data of one hour of image . i can  plot the data on graph according to no of image . But i want to  Display  the Time or minute instead of Image no according to that image .  In the ListBox1 i put all the Image Nos. i have one Image in One second .  I want to display time duration 10min.  But the loop is not working
 `enter code here`

```
 Dim s As New Series
    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    Chart1.Titles.Add("Demo")
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    Dim lMinutes As Long
    Dim lSeconds As Long

    lSeconds = ListBox1.Items.Count

    lMinutes = (Int(lSeconds / 60))

    For t As Integer = 1 To lMinutes
        For y As Integer = 1 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            s.Points.AddXY(t, Val(ListBox1.Items.Item(y).ToString))
        Next
    Next
    Chart1.Series.Add(s)
```

Any suggestion ? Thank you

Comment: Your loop counters should start from 0.  e.g. from t=0 to lminutes. Secondly, if you don't have 60 items in that list box, you'll run from '0' to '0'.. not far thus.

Comment: I have more than 3200...items